# Why and when to use LocalBroadcastManager?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, localbroadcastmanager

I have a gone through couple of LocalBroadcastManager Android tutorials but could not find actual use of it and why to use it?

Comment: Use it when you want to communicate internally from one part of your app to another. Service to activity for example. Activity to fragments, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please post your answer in more details with sample links containing good resources to understand basic functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what the name implies. A `Broadcast`. From one side of your app you broadcast a message that other parts of your app can be listening to.

"good resources to understand basic functionality?". The description above is all the functionality.

An example I can give you is the app I work on.

There's a photo upload on a `Service`. At the end of the upload the server  sends information about the photo and if the user is on the app `main activity` we update the main activity with this extra information. So the `service` sends a `LocalBroadcast` with this information and the `main activity` register/unregister to listen to it during `onStart`/`onStop` callbacks.

The same could be achieved by having the `main activity` binding to the `service`, implements an interface and register itself as a listener but the `LocalBroadcast` is just much simpler to code.

A good alternative to `LocalBrodcast` is to use a bus library like [Otto from Square](http://square.github.io/otto/)